# Complex items in LazyColumn in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Hi I want to Achieve this layout in Jetpack compose

```
Column(scrollable){
   Card(){
      Column()
   }

   Card(){
      Column(){
       Text()
       Text()
       LazyColumn()
      }
   }
}
```

But I Can't use lazycolumn in column that has VerticalScroll

Anyone have a suggestion for this case?
thanks

This Case Like this in xml

```
<NestedScrollView>

  <LinearLayout>

   <CardView>
   </CardView>

   <CardView>

    <LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

     <RecyclerView>

     </RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

   </CardView>

  </LinearLayout>

</NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Why not having a `LazyColumn` at the root and different items in it? Like you'd do with a `RecyclerView` with `itemTypes`

Comment: List items are in second Card()

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can treat your first card as a header of your list items if that makes it easier to visualize for you. What matters is that all your content is scrollable and managed by the same composable: the `LazyColumn`

Comment: I added it's xml version. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I'd stick to what I suggested. I'd do it like this even with XML to avoid handling nested scrolls. It would make your UI more efficient to draw as well as you have a deep tree to draw here – even though it should be less an issue with Compose.